# Angular moment date with GMT date time

Tags: angularjs, date

Hi i'm working with angular with moment API in GMT timezone.
 **form**

```
 $scope.criteria.fromDate = $scope.criteria.fromDate || moment().startOf('day').hour(moment().hour()).minute(moment().minute()).second(moment().second()).toDate();
```

**to**

```
 $scope.criteria.toDate = $scope.criteria.toDate || moment().startOf('day').hour(moment().hour()).minute(moment().minute()).second(moment().second()).toDate();
```

when I console the from date I got `"FROM_DATE" -> "Wed Aug 30 18:30:00 UTC 2017"` and to date is `Wed Aug 30 18:30:00 UTC 2017`

from date is a date with day start time and to date is a date with end day time . that's what i want.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking. If you want the end date to be the end of the day that the user chooses, than add one day to what the user chooses. Moment has a method to add days.

Comment: first of all, if `$scope.criteria.fromDate` and `$scope.criteria.toDate` are populated then you won't even call moment at all.

Comment: @JBNizet from date is a date with day start time and to date is a date with end day time . that's what i want.

Comment: There is no such thing as end day time. The end day time is the start time of the next day. Just as when you say that a store is open from 9 to 20, it means that it closes at 20:00:00